# Which is more stable Ethyl carbocation or Neopentyl carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbocation

As per my knowledge, hyperconjugation is more dominating over inductive effect, so due to three alpha hydrogen ethyl carbocation should be more stable. In some books, while solving questions I observed that answers can match if I take neopentyl carbocation as more stable.

so which one of them is comparatively more stable?

Comment: Watch out: the ethyl carbo cation is a nonclassical cation; under certain conditions it is better described as a protonated ethylene. Stability is also a relative concept, which can't be applied to molecular ions/entities in an absolute manner.

Comment: Can you give specific examples? It may be possible that the underlying concept in some questions is not just the stability of the carbonation, for example, a kinetically controlled reaction...

Comment: Ethyl carbocation is more stable than neopentyl carbocation as we know hyperconjugation is more with ethyl carbocation